# Creating an object based on a string

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am developing a program which allows adding, editing etc of employees. I got stuck on the part of giving the Employee a Department (Department is a class), which I need to create based on its name. Any help?

Code :

Department Class

```
class Department
{
    public Department() { }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> EmployeesAtDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Employee Class

```
abstract class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSurname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Department DepartmentOfEmployee {get; set; }
```

Method for collecting Data

```
public Employee EmpDetails(Employee NewEmp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Name:");
    NewEmp.EmployeeName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Surname:");
    NewEmp.EmployeeSurname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Address:");
    NewEmp.Address = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Grade:");
    NewEmp.Grade = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Salary:");
    NewEmp.Salary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Department of Employee:");
    NewEmp.DepartmentOfEmployee = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Username:");
    NewEmp.Username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Password:");
    NewEmp.Password = Console.ReadLine();

    return NewEmp;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us the definition of `Employee`, `Department` and where/how you store a list of departments we can look up when the user types something (and how that something relates to the department)

Comment: Just instantiate a new instance of Department class and populate the properties

Comment: Do you have a list of departments on some DB? or do you just want to add a new department every time you add an employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't directly convert a string to a class instance. However you could achieve something similar by using the [Factory Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm):

```
public static class DepartmentFactory
{
    public static Department CreateDepartment(string deptStr)
    {
        var dept = new Department();
        // rest of the code

        return dept;
    }
}
```

And your new code:

```
public Employee EmpDetails(Employee NewEmp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Name:");
    NewEmp.EmployeeName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Surname:");
    NewEmp.EmployeeSurname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Address:");
    NewEmp.Address = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Grade:");
    NewEmp.Grade = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Salary:");
    NewEmp.Salary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    // Edit here
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Department of Employee:");
    NewEmp.DepartmentOfEmployee = DepartmentFactory.CreateDepartment(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Username:");
    NewEmp.Username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Password:");
    NewEmp.Password = Console.ReadLine();

    return NewEmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep things tidy here just use an enum and pass in the text value as below:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public AvailableClasses Class { get; private set; }

        public Employee(string name, string myClass)
        {
            Name = name;
            AvailableClasses classEnum;
            if (!Enum.TryParse(myClass, true, out classEnum))
                classEnum = AvailableClasses.Other;

            Class = classEnum;
        }
    }

    public enum AvailableClasses
    {
        Maths,
        Science,
        Other
    }
```